# Silverstripe Translatable can not create translation

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm currently using  Silverstripe 3.4.1 with Silverstripe Translatable 2.2 (it's said to support SS 3.2+)

Everything shows up fine, except that the create button doesn't work at all:

[image]

Anyone has a similar issue or know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

Silverstripe Translatable plugin folder has to be named "translatable" exactly

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/2.2/docs/en/index.md

Comment: How did you install it? It should be named that automatically assuming you installed it with composer